# Microsoft Unified Communications Client API SDK availability

Tags: c#, .net, lync, uccapi

I am using Microsoft Unified Communications Client API SDK to get the presence of a user like available,busy etc.

I am able to install successfully, is there any tutorial to just get the presence of a user using this sdk ?There is no proper tutorial to start for the newbies

Answer (score 1):

The UCCAPI is old, poorly documented and usually reserved for writing solutions against OCS 2007 (although there are exceptions).

If you are coding against the Lync 2010, Lync 2013 or Skype for Business I'd advise using the relevant client SDK instead:-https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933140.aspx

If you are writing an OCS based solution then the following may give you some insight in how to get started http://blogs.technet.com/b/lync/archive/2008/05/13/ucc-api-what-is-it-and-how-does-one-write-an-application-using-it.aspx